# Как быстро распарсить сложный json?

Tags: java, android

Дали задачу распарсить json и вывести  в recylerview .Вот собственно сам json:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "main": "Drizzle",
      "description": "light intensity drizzle",
      "icon": "09d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 80
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 90
  },
  "dt": 1485789600,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0103,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1485762037,
    "sunset": 1485794875
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую библотеку Retrofit и JSON-Schema;

Retrofit (согласно официальному сайту) — типобезопасный HTTP-клиент для Android и Java. Он является незаменимым инструментом для работы с API в клиент-серверных приложениях

Для валидация JSON-документов можете использовать  JSON Schema;
https://habrahabr.ru/post/276305/